# Find the smallest positive $n$ such that $n! \equiv 0 \pmod {425}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

By exhaustion I found $n=17$, but in trying to solve this I can only see that: $$425\space |\space n!\space \longrightarrow\space 425k=n!$$

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor $425 = 5^2 \cdot 17$. Noting that $$n! \equiv 0 \pmod{425} \iff 425 | n! \iff 5^2 |n! \text{ and } 17|n!$$

we see that $n = 17$ is the least solution.

Answer (score 3):

You know that $425=5^2\cdot 17$. Because $n!$ only contains prime factors less than or equal to $n$, and because you nees a factor of $17$, $n\geq 17$. Because $25|17!$, $n=17$ is also sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

If $425=5^2* 17$. The first factorial that contains a factor of the prime $17$ is $17!$. Notice that $17!$ also contains a factor of $5^2$ and so this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$n!\equiv0\bmod425$ means $425$ divides $n!$.

$425=5^2*17$ so it must be at least 17. This is due to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and the definition of factorial. Check $5$ and $10$ are factors of $17!$ so $25$ and $17 $divide $17!$. We are done.